# How to cache Jsonresponse of size more than 512MB in redis

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

Not able to store json of size more than 512MB in redis cache.
**Getting this error:**
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
*Is there any way to store huge response in redis?*

Answer (score 2):

Redis' Strings are limited (currently) to 0.5GB. To store bigger values, you can either chunk them over several String keys or in a Hash. Alternatively, [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson) can handle bigger values as long as the server is set to handle them from a protocol perspective (see the `proto-max-bulk-len` Redis configuration directive).

That said, it is rare that one needs to store such huge documents in this fashion, so perhaps you would like to revisit that requirement/decision.